# OOP PHP two database accessing by two different class, how to access if two tables are in different database

Tags: php

If two database are accessed using two different classes, say class A for DB1 and class B for DB2,  then is it possible to get the values from two tables in OOP PHP if table 1 is in DB1 and table 2 is in DB2, but PHP doesnot allow mltiple inheritance please help me out i am stuck here.

Comment: From what i can tell, you first must have a database user able to query both databases (permission-wise). Then you can setup BaseDatabaseClass which is extended by A (only DB1), B (only DB2) and a new class C, which is able to query both. I've managed something similar using PropelOrm a while back. Extra note: for querying multiple databases in the same SQL command, you need to prefix the tablenames with the database name (eg: `DB1`.table1.column_name instead of just table1.column_name)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try that.

Comment: I thought of going Laravel, and it give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO we can initialize instance of more than one database. Also Laravel is the solution.